# How to insert a pandas data frame in one cell in excel (using openpyxl), where the values will be separated with comma?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, openpyxl

I would like to insert a pandas data frame in one cell in excel (using openpyxl), where the values of the data frame will be separated with comma. Until now I have achieved to print the data frame in excel but in multiple cells, as it is presented in the following script and table. Moreover, in the last figure , the table that I want to print in excel is presented.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook 
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1'] 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}) 
df_transpose=df.T
rows_materials= dataframe_to_rows(df.T, index=False,header=False)

for r_idx_materials, row in enumerate(rows_materials, 1):
    for c_idx_materials, value in enumerate(row, 1): 
         ws.cell(row=r_idx_materials, column=c_idx_materials, value=value)

wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the contents of the list in as a string like this

```
wb = load_workbook(r'C:\temp\temp.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1'] 
my_list = ["1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': my_list}) 
df_transpose=df.T
rows_materials= dataframe_to_rows(df.T, index=False,header=False)

for r_idx_materials, row in enumerate(rows_materials, 1):
    for c_idx_materials, value in enumerate(row, 1): 
         ws.cell(row=r_idx_materials, column=c_idx_materials, value=value)

wb.save(r'C:\temp\temp.xlsx')
```

Output
[image]